# Does Xcode4.2 still support remote debugging or have options for debugging as root

Tags: xcode

I saw some other questions and walkthroughs for enabling remote debugging in xcode 4.2 to run and debug programs as root, but the walkthroughs look like they are for an older version of Xcode. Towards the last steps I can't find the options described in the apple documentation or in the walkthroughs Ifound on stackoverflow. Does anyone know where the remote debugging options for the new version of xcode were hidden or how I could go about enabling remote debugging for my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 4 does not support remote debugging anymore. It's a surprising oversight and a real drag.